# Find minimum number of iterations to reach a certain sum

Tags: summation

Im trying to solve this problem since weeks, but couldn't arrive to a solution.
You start with two numbers X & Y both equal to 1. Only valid options are `X+Y` or `Y+X` at a time. We need to find minimum number of iterations need to reach a specific number.

eg : if the number is 5

$X=1, Y=1; X = X+Y$

$X=2, Y=1; Y = X+Y$

$X=2, Y=3; Y = Y+X$

$X=2, Y=5;$ Stop answer reached

My take : If a number is odd let's say 23, decrement by 1. Now value = 22. Find the largest number that divides 22 = 11. Now reach the number by adding 1's so that:

$X=11; Y=1 ; Y=Y+X$

$X=11; Y=12; X=X+Y$

$X=23$, answer reached

But the problem with this approach is I cannot recursively reach a specific number, as even if I reach a certain point, say X = required value, the Y value gets misplaced and I cant reuse it to reach another value

Comment: Seems like you have the answer in your solution.  Compute both X = X+Y and Y = Y+X at every iteration and assign the higher of these to the prior lower value of X or Y.  I am rushing but may be correct

Comment: Consider https://oeis.org/A178031.

Comment: @satishramanathan seems incorrect, eg : try for 9 you get stuck at X=5 and Y=8 niether reaches to 9

Comment: @IvanNeretin X=X+Y and Y=Y+X are only valid operations, in the link you provided, X=X+1 and Y=Y+1 is valid

Comment: Even though Ivan Neretin's link doesn't apply exactly, you should try solving the problem for small values of $N$ and look for a pattern. (If you're programming to find these values, you should use a breadth-first search.)

Comment: @CarlHeckman actually I was thinking about backtracking

Comment: Consider https://oeis.org/A178047 ... This has your sequence out to N = 21. It's also clear (by induction) that X/Y is always in lowest terms. It looks like this is the same sequence, but the page doesn't explain how to get the Nth term.